# Trigger condition in all rows

Tags: oracle, triggers

I'm trying to implement a traffic fine control system. When a radar observation is introduced in the table OBSERVACION the trigger should check if there is a row with an observation over the same car, and then calculate the fine cost.

I want a trigger to check a condition statement in every row of the table. I mean, I want the trigger condtion to check all the values in the table and find if one of them is equal to the NEW value introduced. Something like this:

```
WHEN(NEW.fecha_foto = fecha_foto)AND...
```

Where fecha_foto is any value in the table.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not possible, and it isn't really desirable.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I have a table with traffic fines rows and i want to check the time between the new row and a previous existing one.

Comment: what business logic are you trying to implement?

Comment: I'm trying to implement a traffic fine control system. When a radar observation is introduced in the table OBSERVACION the trigger should check if there is a row with an observation over the same car, and then calculate the fine cost.

Comment: I posted a solution, but as someone else pointed out, it leads to Oracle's "mutating trigger" problem.  Which is why I really don't like using triggers in Oracle for anything but audit tables.  You're better off using a stored procedure or external client program to calculate this before attempting to insert the record in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trigger which issues DML (including SELECT) against the same table which owns the trigger raises the spectre of ORA-4091, the mutating table exception.  Oracle hurls this error because it expects the outcome of a transaction to be deterministic, and a trigger which issue DML on its own table introduces uncertainty into proceedings.

Mutating table is a reliable indicator of bad design, specifically a bad data model and that seems to be the case here.

If the value of a fine is dependent on the outcome of a single observation then it is okay for FINE to be a column on the OBSERVACION table.  However your business rules indicate that the value may depend on several observations, if they fall within a certain period.  In this scenario the fine should be in a table of its own.  You would need a foreign key between OBSERVACION and MULTA to indicate which observations are covered by a particular fine.

Comment: I finally solved it introducing the data y want to compare in a temporary table.

Comment: To be frank that sounds like more of a kludge than a proper solution.