# trigger constraint error sql oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, constraints

I get an error when trying to compile the following trigger...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DegreePart_CreditsMax
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON DEGREE_MODULE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF(SUM(NUMBER_OF_CREDITS) FROM DEGREE_MODULE INNER JOIN MODULE ON DEGREE_MODULE.MODULE_ID = MODULE.MODULE_ID
        WHERE OPTIONAL = 'N' AND DEGREE_ID = :NEW.DEGREE_ID > 120)
THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -- Error Message
-20001, 
'Degree must not contain compulsary modules worth over 120 credits.' );
END IF;
END;
/
```

I'm trying to check that when a module is added the sum of all the current compulsory modules for that degree plus the new module is less than 120???

error is...

> Error(2,27): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FROM" when expecting one of the following:     ) , * & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>     <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec as between || multiset member submultiset

Comment: Have you tried `IF EXISTS(SELECT SUM(NUMBER_OF_CREDITS) ...`

Comment: I THEN GET...Error(2,66): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "JOIN" when expecting one of the following:     ) , with group having intersect minus start union where    connect

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trigger condition in all rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455690/trigger-condition-in-all-rows)

Comment: This isn't going to work.  Once you solve all the syntax issues you'll get a "Mutating tables" runtime exception.  See my explanation in the qiggers.uestion I reference above.  But basically you can't do this sort of logic in triggers.

Comment: what do you suggest i do to implement this constraint?

Comment: You usually have to implement this sort of logic with an on-commit materialized view where the constraint limitation's part of the underlying table supporting the materialized view.

Comment: APC is right. Deleting my answer.

Comment: Tom Kyte has an example here:  http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4233459000346171405

Answer (score 0):

You could try ‘rephrasing’ your condition like this:

```
IF EXISTS (
  SELECT SUM(NUMBER_OF_CREDITS)
  FROM DEGREE_MODULE
    INNER JOIN MODULE ON DEGREE_MODULE.MODULE_ID = MODULE.MODULE_ID
  WHERE OPTIONAL = 'N' AND DEGREE_ID = :NEW.DEGREE_ID
  HAVING SUM(NUMBER_OF_CREDITS) > 120
)
THEN
  …
```